# How to make a image vertical in Tkinter using canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a project atm, and i am trying to figure out a way to make my image vertical, ill be using a monitor turned vertically so i need all my information vertical:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("img11.jpg"))
canvas_image = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500,bg="white", highlightthickness=0) 
canvas_image.create_image((100, 100), image=img)
canvas_image.place(x=300, y=400)
```

This is the code i have at the moment.
any help?

Comment: If you are on MS Windows and you want to physically rotate your monitor then just go to display.orientation and select portrait. Everything displayed should be automatically rotated including mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to rotate  the image:

```py
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Rotated image on Canvas")
root.geometry("300x300")

pil_image = Image.open("flower.jpg")
pil_image = pil_image.resize((300, 300))

pil_image = pil_image.rotate(-90)  # or 90 degrees

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

canvas_image = tk.Canvas(root, height=300, width=300, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
canvas_image.create_image((150, 150), image=img)
canvas_image.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Creates this application:

[image]